# how do you make log4net output to current working directory?

Tags: log4net

Is it possible to have log4net put its log files relative to the current working directory instead of the directory where the application resides?

In other words, if I run ..\myapp.exe, I don't want the log files in ..\  I want them in .\

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ended up looking at the log4net source and determined I can implement my own appender that extends FileAppender and overrides the File property.

```
class CWDFileAppender : FileAppender
{
    public override string File
    {
        set
        {
            base.File = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), value);
        }
    }
}
```

I just use CWDFileAppender in my configuration.

Comment: Hey kiko, put such updates in your answer. keeps the thread clean, unless you have the correct answer to your own question...

Comment: This worked well for me, although I inherrited from RollingFileAppender. I also put it in a common library I use so I can use it across all my projects. Remember to specify the assembly as well in your config if you do this.

<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="My.Library.CurrentDirectoryRollingFileAppender, My.Library">

Answer (score 2):

Not possible from the config file, as per [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.File.html). It may be possible if you are configuring it manually from inside your program though:

```
public static log4net.Appender.IAppender CreateFileAppender(string name,
string fileName)
{
  log4net.Appender.FileAppender appender = new
log4net.Appender.FileAppender();
  appender.Name = name;
  appender.File = fileName;
  appender.AppendToFile = true;

  log4net.Layout.PatternLayout layout = new
log4net.Layout.PatternLayout();
  layout.ConversionPattern = "%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n";
  layout.ActivateOptions();

  appender.Layout = layout;
  appender.ActivateOptions();

  return appender;
}
```

You can then associate it with the logger as follows:

```
AddAppender("Log4net.MainForm", CreateFileAppender("FileAppender",   
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "foo.log")));
```

Comment: That confirms what I was thinking. I posted my own answer with a pretty easy way to make it configurable.